# Get aggregated message on user's timeline in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j for my social projects where User can create, like and share a post, and can follow each other and user can see their follower's created, liked and shared post on his timeline.
I want aggregated message like : "You, Harry and other 20 has shared this post"

```
MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(f:User)-[p:CREATED]-(d) 
RETURN d, 
   SIZE( ()-[:LIKED]->(d) ) as likecount, 
   SIZE( ()-[:SHARED]->(d) ) as sharecount,  
   SIZE( (n)-[:LIKED]->(d) ) as likestatus, 
   SIZE( (n)-[:SHARED]->(d) ) as sharestatus, 
   count(*) as postcount, 
CASE 
  WHEN sharestatus = 1 
    THEN "You" 
  WHEN sharecount > 1 
    THEN "abc and xyz share this post" 
END 
ORDER BY d.updated_at DESC 
SKIP 0 
LIMIT 25
```

I tried above query but didn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you confirm return values of: `MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'}) RETURN count(*)`. `MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(f:User) RETURN count(*)`, and `MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(f:User)-[p:CREATED]-(d) RETURN count(*)`? What version of neo4j? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jacob.mccrumb. Used version is Neo4j 3.4.8. and I Want to return all post of user's own and follow user's post. and I also have to display message strip according to time on user's timeline like "you, Sushil and other 21 has shared this post" or "you, Sushil and other 16 has like this post"

Comment: @Nandana - I understand the goal, can you run the various queries I mentioned above and post their output? Wanted to confirm the nodes exist in the graph before doing any further troubleshooting. Thanks!

Comment: @jacob.mccrumb All nodes are exist in the graph. output details are as follows -

1. Output of this query is MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'}) RETURN count(*) is 1

2. Output of MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(f:User) RETURN count(*) is 19

3. Output of query MATCH (n:User {user_id:'5bbc7962b87e07476f6c04db'})-[:FOLLOWS]->(f:User)-[p:CREATED]-(d) RETURN count(*) is 68

Comment: Hmm in that case I would recommend adding one line at a time from your queries RETURN (start with just d, then add the next line etc) and see when it starts returning data? I don't see anything wrong with the query so pinning down which line fails will help.